# How to remove all points that could be linearly interpolated from graph data?

Tags: algorithm, excel, vba, charts

Given two columns of graph data in Excel, how can it be "un-interpolated" - i.e. compressed down to the least number of rows that would produce the same line graph?

A simple example:

```
x    y
1    4
2    5
3    6
4    3
5    0
```

would become:

```
x    y
1    4
3    6
5    0
```

...since this would produce exactly the same lines but with "in between" points removed.

Is there an existing macro, add-in, online tool etc. that could be used to produce such results - or if not, perhaps someone could invent such an algorithm?

**EDIT:** For a real-world example, the graph below was reverse-engineered using [WebPlotDigitizer](http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer/app/). The pink dots mark the points, which may not have been perfectly converted into floating point values - so ideally the algorithm would include a small "margin for error" to account for this.

[image: Graph]

Comment: Great question. What is the scale we are talking about? How much lines will the original consist?

Comment: Thanks. There's quite a lot of data as it was all produced using [WebPlotDigitizer](http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer/app/). Am looking for the general case of how to do this.

Comment: Form equation of line by 1st 2 points. Keep checking sequentially whether subsequent points obey current equation. If they do, then delete last point, else form a new line equation.

Comment: How would you do it with pen and paper?

Comment: These two sets of data would produce different curves if using spline interpolation.

Comment: @jacouh Fair point - have just updated the question title to specify linear interpolation

Comment: @Steve Chambers, great, your assumption is perfect...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett To do this by pen and paper would be fairly simple: Produce a line graph by joining all points and then judge where the straight lines fall and remove the points in between... But think this "judgment" could be a bit tricky to automate. It would be easy enough if it weren't for the "margin for error" aspect (which is particularly relevant to my use case since the data was reverse-engineered from a graph). As commented by coproc below, a simple error for each pair of points suffers from the flaw of missing a slowly bending curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
Sub RemoveLinearlyDependentPoints()

    Dim rngX As Range, rngY As Range, rngData As Range, rngRemove As Range
    Dim lCount As Long, dSlope1 As Double, dSlope2 As Double
    Dim varX As Variant, varY As Variant
    Const EPSILON = 0.0001

    ' Change ranges as needed
    Set rngX = Range("A1:A5")
    Set rngY = Range("B1:B5")
    Set rngData = Union(rngX, rngY)

    rngData.Sort key1:=rngX, Order1:=xlAscending

    ' Working with arrays instead of ranges is faster,
    ' can make a big different for large datasets
    varX = rngX.Value
    varY = rngY.Value

    With WorksheetFunction
        For lCount = 1 To rngX.Count - 2
            dSlope1 = .Slope(Array(varX(lCount, 1), varX(lCount + 1, 1)), Array(varY(lCount, 1), varY(lCount + 1, 1)))
            dSlope2 = .Slope(Array(varX(lCount + 1, 1), varX(lCount + 2, 1)), Array(varY(lCount + 1, 1), varY(lCount + 2, 1)))
            ' If slopes are the same, point in row lCount+1 can be removed
            If Abs(dSlope1 - dSlope2) < EPSILON Then
                If Not rngRemove Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngRemove = Union(rngRemove, .Index(rngData, lCount + 1, 0))
                Else
                    Set rngRemove = .Index(rngData, lCount + 1, 0)
                End If
            End If
        Next lCount
    End With

    ' Mark the cells red for checking
    rngRemove.Cells.Interior.Color = vbRed
    ' Uncomment the below to delete the cells
    'rngRemove.EntireRow.Delete (xlUp)
End Sub
```

The idea is that, if the data are sorted wrt their `x` coordinate, we only need to keep the points in which the slope changes. So whenever the slope does not change in two consecutive pairs `(A,B)` and `(B,C)`, `B` can be removed because it is in the same line as `(A,C)`. We need to check the slope only because the data is sorted with respect to `x`, and therefore we know that `x_A <= x_B <= x_C`.

For the given example, 
**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Comparing the slopes between points `i`,`i+1` and `i+1`,`i+2` is not perfectly safe as a slowly bending curve will collapse to one line. It would be better to set up the Hesse normal forms of the lines through points `i`,`i+2`, then `i`,`i+3`, and so on as long as the points in between (`i+1` then `i+1`,`i+2` and so on) do not exceed a given maximal distance to the corresponding line.

Comment: @coproc Thanks for the comment. Could you help me by clarifying a couple of points: (i) the comparison I suggested will fail whenever the absolute value difference of two different consecutive slopes is less than a predefined accuracy. Will it fail in any other case?
(ii) Could you elaborate on the benefit of using the Hesse normal forms? It seems a lot more work, as it checks all the pairs, not only the two consecutive ones (iii) is the criterion  of `a given maximal distance` computationally more robust than comparing the slope difference of consecutive points? Could you give an example?

Comment: ad (i): if the slopes are `s`, `s+e`, `s+2e`, `s+3e`, ... with `e<EPSILON` then your check will remove all intermediate points. Well, this is not very probable I admit, and your algorithm will work without problems with real data. But one can close this hole with little more effort.

Comment: ad (ii): computing the Hesse normal form is not much effort and you only do it O(n) times: for points `0`,`2`, until `0`,`j` (with `j` being the point index where the intermediate points are not all in the `EPSILON`-strip around the line `0`,`j`), then you start with the Hesse normal form for points `j-1`,`j+1` until `j-1`,`j+k` ... The number of distance compuations for intermediate points is O(j^2 + k^2 + ...), a worst complexity of O(n^2).  Ok, this is the price. You can limit the number of distance computations by limiting the range for `j`,`k` ... with a possibly not minimal result set.

Comment: Any numerical algorithm works correctly within a specified tolerance.. I cannot see why this is an argument in favor of the Hesse normal form, as it holds for this as well (and it has `O(n^2)` worst case complexity instead of `O(nlogn)` which is the above implementation). Actually, the OP wants to remove all points that almost fall into a line, so tweaking the `EPSILON` parameter should do it. For a very slow-bending curve, `EPSILON = 10e-12` should work.

Comment: Thanks both. I definitely take coproc's point. It doesn't matter how small `EPSILON` is - for a slow bending curve where the bend is a continuous change in slope that's smaller than `EPSILON`, the method breaks down. Have accepted the answer as it's the only one, a very good effort and a nice compact piece of code that should work for the majority of cases - but would be interested to see how the loophole could be closed. (I'm not at all worried about efficiency by the way). Might consider putting up a bounty at a later date...

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks for accepting! I see where you (and coproc) are coming from, and I am keen on learning a more robust approach. My hunch is that any method will resort to some kind of comparison, and therefore will be correct up to given tolerance. For instance, the Hesse normal form will check if the distance of a point from a line  formed by two other points is zero or not. The line equation is specified imperfectly as well, subject to round-off errors. This (or any other) approach may be more robust, but we cannot know unless we benchmark them. Keep us posted, interesting problem!